# Induction step of a power of 2 with ceiling function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I have to prove the following excercise:

"Determine whether each of these proposed definitions is a valid recursive definition of a function f from the set of nonnegative integersto the set of integers. If f is well defined, find a formula for $f(n)$ when $n$ is a nonnegative integer and prove that your formula is valid."

The proposition is $f(0)=2, f(n)=f(n-1)$ if $n$ is odd and $n >= 1$ and $f(n)=2f(n-2)$ if $n>=2$

The formula I found is:

$$f(n) = 2^{\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil}$$

I already did the basis step where $f(1)=2, f(2)=2, f(3)=4$ and $f(4)=4$ so $f(n)$ is true for $n <= 4$.

Now comes the Inductive Step where I want to prove that $P(k+1)$ is true given that $P(k-3)$ is also true. Is this a correct assumption for the inductive step? If so, how should I proceed with the proof?

Comment: What is $f$? $\quad$

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand your question of "What is $f$". Did I miss something?

Comment: You want to prove that $f(n) = 2^{\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil}$, but you never say what $f$ is.

Comment: The original exercise says: "Determine whether each of these proposed definitions is a valid recursive definition of a function $f$ from the set of nonnegative integersto the set of integers. If $f$ is well defined, find a formula for $f(n)$ when $n$ is a nonnegative integer and prove that your formula is valid." The above formula is what I found. Maybe I should delete this post and write it again with the complete description.

Comment: Oh, I see.  So, you probably were given something like $f(n+1) = f(n)f(n-1)$ (not exactly that, mind you, but a recursive expression), and some base case $f(1) = 1, f(0) = 1$ (again, just an example)?  If so, you can just edit that information into your current question.

Comment: I have edited the original question, please let me know if it is clear now.

Comment: I really need help on this problem, I will very much appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

For $n=0$, we have $f(0) = 2 \not= 2^{\left\lceil\frac{0}{2}\right\rceil} = 1$, so your formula cannot be correct.  Looking at the first few terms:
$$f(0) = 2$$
$$f(1) = f(1-1) = 2$$
$$f(2) = 2f(0) = 4$$
$$f(3) = f(3-1) = 4$$
$$\vdots$$

Personally, I'd try to find a formula for even $n$ (that is, $n=2k$), use induction to prove it, and then use the relation $f(2k+1) = f(2k)$.

Comment: Yes, yesterday I noticed my mistake and I think that the function can be $f(0) = 2^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor+1}$  for $n >= 0$. However, your approach of finding a formula for even $n$ seems better because it would be easier to work with than a function with ceiling/floor operators. Thank you.